# Read data from USB serial device

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, serial-port, usb

I am trying to read data from a USB serial RFID device in Ubuntu.

The device is: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8852

The device is recognised under Ubuntu as:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

If I use programs such as 'screen' or 'minicom' when I touch an RFID tag to the reader, a unique number is shown on screen.

I want to be able to get this data through terminal. Then when I have this data process if however necessary.

My question is, how can I get the data like I see it in these programs? I would like to either write a bash or PHP script to get at the data.

Thanks

Comment: Has the user that PHP is running as have the correct rights to that directory?

Comment: You need something that can watch the device and do something with the output. PHP can do this by setting a script that loops continuously, but its not well designed for this senario. What are you trying to do with the data once its received?

Comment: So I have been able to get the output with:

'sudo cat < /dev/ttyUSB0'

I just need a way of capturing that in php.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use PHP (*nix/Windows) then you are looking for the PHP `dio` (Direct I/O) extension:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php

From PHP manual:

> PHP supports the direct io functions as described in the Posix
>   Standard (Section 6) for performing I/O functions at a lower level
>   than the C-Language stream I/O functions (fopen(), fread(),..). The
>   use of the DIO functions should be considered only when direct control
>   of a device is needed. In all other cases, the standard filesystem
>   functions are more than adequate.